# Error while doing sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

I always get the following errors when I do sudo `apt-get update`. How do I fix them?

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/partner i386 Packages  
(/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run `apt-get update` to correct these problems
```

Comment: please run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and let us know what the output is - copy and paste the output into your question.

Comment: here is the output.. Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it says you have a duplicate in your sources list. How you fix this can depend on the Package Manager(s) that you use. To go straight to the sources list, open a Terminal and issue the command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Look for the duplicate. You can disable one by putting a `#` at the beginning of the line or removing duplicate lines.

```
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/partner
```